# How to properly use Properties.Settings?

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid, system.componentmodel, properties.settings

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 where I have a project, called Utilities, containing my `settings.settings` file which I want to access from other projects in the solution.

In another project, I want to let the user manage the settings in a Windows Form using `PropertyGrid`. I also want to customize it using `System.ComponentModel` settings. I've tried to apply the `ComponentModel` settings such as `DescriptionAttribute` in the `Settings.Designer.cs` file which worked, but as it say in the comments of the file, the changes to that file when regenerated.

So my questions is as follows:

1. How do I access the `Properties.Settings` from another project?
2. How do I customize the `PropertyGrid` without changing the `Settings.Designer.cs` file?
3. As mentioned, I let the user manage the settings from a form. However, I want to restore the values when the users presses Cancel button. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set the Access Modifier in the setting designer to public (default is internal)
2. I would go with a wrapper-class for your Settings (just a lot of attribute-decorated properties with get/set pointing to the original settings). This code could be auto-generated from the  Settings.Designer.cs file.
3. Save the previous settings, e.g. via serialization (binary or xml), to a variable. Then you can restore it by setting the properties to the saved value.

Comment: I was hoping that I wouldn't need to save previous settings. After all, there are no changes made, since the user is pressing Cancel. I'll create a wrapper-class that handles that for me. Thank you for your response!

Comment: You can take the opposite approach, that the user will be editing just a copy and you will assign this copy to the original Settings only if he submits with an OK click or similar.